# Running two functions at the same time in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I try to make a Bot which can speak to you and can do special things like a timer. I want that the timer can run while the user can input more questions or something to talk to the bot.
But now when "Timer_end" gets activated as a new thread by doing threading.Timer(time_wait, Timer_end).start() the sound winsound.Beep(800,250) plays but the "Speak("ALERT!")" will not activate.

```
import os
import time
import threading
import winsound

ki_speak="yes"
user_speak="yes"
time_wait=0
text=""
user=""

def Timer_start():
    Speak("Timer settings:")
    Speak("Seconds:")
    seconds=int(input())
    Speak("Minutes:")
    minutes=int(input())
    Speak("Hours:")
    hours=int(input())
    global time_wait
    time_wait=0
    while seconds!=0:
        time_wait+=1
        seconds-=1
    while minutes!=0:
        time_wait+=60
        minutes-=1
    while hours!=0:
        time_wait+=3600
        hours-=1
    threading.Timer(time_wait, Timer_end).start()

def Timer_end():
    winsound.Beep(800,250)
    winsound.Beep(600,250)
    Speak("ALERT!")

def Speak(text):
    print(text)
    if user_speak=="Yes" or user_speak=="yes":
        global user
        SpeakFile = open("User_Speak.vbs","w")
        SpeakFile.write('textvbs = ("')
        SpeakFile.write(str(user))
        SpeakFile.write('")\nset objvoice = createobject ("SAPI.spvoice")\nobjvoice.speak textvbs')
        SpeakFile.close()
        os.system("User_Speak.vbs")
        user=""
    if ki_speak=="Yes" or ki_speak=="yes":
        SpeakFile = open("Ki_Speak.vbs","w")
        SpeakFile.write('textvbs = ("')
        SpeakFile.write(str(text))
        SpeakFile.write('")\nset objvoice = createobject ("SAPI.spvoice")\nobjvoice.speak textvbs')
        SpeakFile.close()
        os.system("Ki_Speak.vbs")
        text=""

def main():
    if user=="b":
        CRASH
    elif user=="hello":
        Speak("Hey")
    elif user=="t":
        Timer_start()

while True:
    user=str(input())
    main()
```

Comment: Might be easier just to use `msvcrt.getch()` in a loop to get input characters one by one in a loop and test the timer as you go. No need for threads then.

Comment: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/06/running-functions-as-threads-in-python.html and then this x2